# OpenZ - OpenBravo ERP compatibility

Tags: openbravo

I have an OpenZ 2.6.80 (fork of the OpenBravo project version 2.50) and I can not see a "Module Management" section. It is completely unclear for me how to install an .obx modules there. Also how to develop a packages. Probably somebody know about specific documentation for OpenZ or about modules installation or development.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hi Catherine,

```
     If you need to install .obx file through command line , 
     Please follow the underline link.
```

[Obx Installation Link.](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50%3aDevelopers_Guide/Concepts/Modularity#Module%20Manager%20Console%20%28MMC%29)

If you need to install via command line : Extract the .obx file and paste in module folder.

then follow the mentioned commands:

1 . ant update.database -Dforce=true  2 . ant compile.complete  3 .     ant smartbuild.

For Packaging the module please follow the link 
[Creating the Module and packaging the module](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50%3aDevelopers_Guide/How_To_Create_and_Package_a_Module)

Answer (score 0):

- If you need to create a new New module in openbravo [see here for more information](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50%3aDevelopers_Guide/How_To_Create_and_Package_a_Module#Creating_a_Module), first you need
  to login with "*System Administrator*" role using Openbravo User
  credentials(Openbravo/openbravo). [See here for changing the roles in
  openbravo](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50%3aConfiguration_Manual/Roles_and_users#Changing_Roles)
- If you have obx file(module) with you, you just need to deploy the module [deploy and installing module](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50%3aDevelopers_Guide/How_To_Create_and_Package_a_Module#Deploying.2FCompiling_a_module)